# How to fill a text field with a hidden value?

Tags: javascript

I am auto populating text fields from a database and I am also validating these fields in case someone mistypes anything. If validation fails I show the error messages but the fields get back the original values.

Is there a way to refill those text fields with something like hidden values to hold the mistyped value.

So this email field gets populated with a value from the database on page load.

```
<td align="left">
        <s:textfield name="emailId" id="emailId" label="Email" cssClass="dataFieldCell3" value="%{#signerslist.email}"  />
</td>
```

So if accidentally the value is changed I want to get that changed value and hold it because I am showing the error message for it without letting it go back and get the original value.

I am not sure what to do after this JavaScript.

```
function getIncorrectValue() {
    var emailValue = document.getElementById('emailId').value;
}
```

Comment: What is setting them to the original values?  Seems like you're missing some context in the code provided.

Comment: Mike what do you mean "holding" the value? If you don't want any changes to be completed it would be easiest to simply populate the form from your server and then disable the input fields by setting the "disabled" attribute. If you do want the value held for some reason, could you clarify what you mean  by that?

Comment: So in startup we populate the fields (original values). Now if I change the original value to something else (invalid email) I show error messages. So currently even after showing the error messages the page re loads and gets back the original value so I don't want this. I want the invalid email address typed by the user. Hope it is clear.

Comment: @Mike: First you need to find out what's setting the value in the first place.  Presumably that operation is happening again when the page reloads.  So you want to make that operation *conditionally* happen.

Comment: I tried it that way too. I say if the error message is there get the value from the text field and assign it back to the text field to show it but looks liek the operation happens too fast and the page loads and it gets the original value again.

Comment: @Mike So you load up the page. It shows values from the server. You happen to change the e-mail to an incorrect value. It shows an error message. If you don't change it to a correct value, and leave/refresh, whenever you come back to the page it shows the data you entered incorrectly and not the correct data from the server. Did I get that right?

Comment: If I type incorrect data then leave the page and come back then it gets the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery, you can add data to your DOM. This data is a string model, which means it will be an invisible or hidden data attached to your HTML element.

```
function getIncorrectValue() {
    var emailValue = document.getElementById('emailId').value;
    $('#emailId').data('incorrectValue', emailValue);
}
```

Then you can retrieve that data later by doing:

```
var emailValue = $('#emailId').data('incorrectValue');
```

Comment: I need to put it back in the text field.

Comment: Hi Mike! Have you included jQuery in your project? This solution requires jQuery because the .data() function is in the jQuery library.

Comment: // this will put the value back in the text field:

`var emailValue = $('#emailId').data('incorrectValue');
document.getElementById('emailId').value = emailValue;`